# Using the Gmail API from within an Android application

Tags: android, api, gmail

I need to download all of a user's sent emails from within an Android application. In the case of Gmail accounts I want to use the Gmail API. The documentation around Gmail API, OAuth 2.0 etc is giving me a HUGE headache and I'm pretty lost with it all. All I'm trying to do at this stage is create a working Gmail service object that I can query on.

I'm currently trying the following:

1. Adding a 'Sign in with Google' integration to get me a `GoogleSignInAccount` the way that [this guide tells me to](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) (also requesting an Id token).
2. Making a new `GoogleCredential` and setting the token that I got back above (retrieved with `account.getIdToken`) with:

   ```
           GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
               .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
               .build().setAccessToken(account.getIdToken()).createScoped(Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY));
   ```
3. Creating a `Gmail` object with:

   ```
        Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).build();
   ```

But whenever I try to use this Gmail object I get the following response:

```
W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  W/System.err:   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
```

Am I going about this completely the wrong way? Is there a different way that I should be creating my Gmail object or authenticating it? I don't think the [Java Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) is much help to me here as I can't see how the authentication method would translate into the Android environment.